# wso2 : ESB faultsequence

Tags: sequence, fault, wso2-esb

**how to use faultsequence of proxy in esb**

i want to use faultsequence when occur a fault in EndPoint. for example i stop service1 using jconsole and want to route message to service2 when call proxy service. but when i call proxy using soapui it show fault this message : *The system is attempting to access an inactive service..*

```
<target>
  <inSequence >
     <send>
        <endpoint name="cal" >     
         <address uri="http://localhost:9763/services/service1/"/>   
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <faultSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="text" value="An unexpected error occured for service"/>
        <property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
    </log>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://localhost:9763/services/service2/"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </faultSequence>
```

please guide me!

Answer (score 1):

When your endpoint 1 is inactive it returns a soap fault and you want it to go to the fault sequence. But at the moment that fault sequence is considered as a response and it is sent to the client (soap ui).

In WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 onwards, there is a new property FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT added. By setting this property, soap faults will be directed to fault sequence. You can do your next logics when you are in the fault sequence (for example invoking another sequence).

Refer [1] for a sample proxy service.

[1] http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html

Comment: Do this cater your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your exact scenario is apart of your main end point if it faild you need to route the message to secondary endpoint.

Correct approach to your implementation is not using the fault sequence right approach is using fail over endpoint. You can find reference document at [1][2].

For sample you can refer "Sample 53: Failover sending among 3 endpoints" [3].

[1].http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/endpoint_guide.html#FoEp
[2].http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Failover+Endpoint
[3].http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/samples/endpoint_mediation_samples.html

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Comment: Thank you dear Dharshana. yeah, it is correct your assumption but address of my secondary endpoint is dynamic and i need a new sequence(fault sequence) that load class mediator into it and rout message to new destination that is specified by class mediator . so i think need to a fault sequence. is it true? because endpoint in fail over is static!

Comment: It is possible to call another sequence inside fault sequence. Yes for your scenario you need to use the fault sequence. You can set a targer fault sequence as below  <target faultSequence="test">
      <inSequence>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target> then you can implement new endpoint logic inside the test sequence